# IIS Certificate is being auto-created and changed on bindings

Tags: azure, ssl, iis

I have an Azure VM running IIS. Periodically a new certificate is auto-generated, and the binding is automatically switched on my site to the new certificate. When this happens, it essentially breaks the site. The devices connecting to the site don't recognize the new certificate.

The certificate is always named something like `[IIS] (any site), (any host) @ 2022/01/04 8:15:00`. The issuer is R3. They are WebHosting certs. As soon as I switch back to my old certificates, communication continues immediately.

[image: Certificate Example]

The Azure VM is a Windows Server 2019, running IIS 10.

What could be creating these certificates, and how can I stop it?

Comment: "Issued by R3" indicates that you have configured this machine to enroll Let's Encrypt certificates automatically (many ways, so not sure which way you configured). If you don't want that to happen, roll back the relevant changes.

Comment: @LexLi thanks, I'll look into that. We never configured Let's Encrypt on this server, but it's possible that Azure did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@LexLi was correct in their comment above; Let's Encrypt was installed (though I'm not sure why) and it had a scheduled task that was creating the certificates. I missed it because it was called *"win-acme"*. I deleted all the folders and exe's for that, then the scheduled task, and then the certificates.